# Updating SQL table converting varchar to int

Tags: php, sql, join, select, sql-insert

I currently have a table `new_funeralhomes` as below, which has the new data i wish to add to another table:

[image],

Within that table, i can easily send address,postal,phone, website and email to this table `addressTest`:

[image].

However as you can see by the `new_funeralhomes` table, the city/state are text value and in the second table (`addressTest`) they are int values connecting to these tables:

`city`:

[image],

`province`:

[image].

How would i go about updating the `addressTest` table with the new city and province? The iid and id values match up and are the same throughout.

Im newer to this so any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an `insert ... select`  statement with `join`s. The logic is:

```
insert into addressTest
    (address, province, postcalcode, city, primaryphone, secondaryphoe, website)
select
    n.address
    p.id,
    n.postcal,
    c.id,
    n.phone,
    n.phone2,
    n.website
from new_funeralhomes n
inner join city c on c.name = n.city
inner join province p on p.name = n.state
```

Side note: it *seems* like the source table has less columns than the target; I adapted the column list for what seem to be the matching columns - you might need to review that so it properly matches your requirement (but the `join` logic, which is the heart of your question, stays the same).